# Javascript - make array of objects and understanding constructors

Tags: javascript, class, object, constructor

I know this question has been asked before, but they're always project specific and I can't find what i'm looking for.

I need an array of objects in javascript. I have declared a class as :

```
var svgData = {.....}
```

(the keyword class isn't available in esversion: 5) 
and I have an array variable :

```
var svgContent = [];
```

I tried doing it like you would in C# where you would write :

```
svgContent[0] = new svgData();
```

However you would normally create a constructor for it, which as far as I can tell, doesn't exist in javascript. I have been using a function like this:

```
function SvgData (....) {
    this.var = ...; 
    etc.
}
```

but the problem is that there is no link between this and the class, and as such I have an issue that when I try to access a variable in the array using a for loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < length; i ++){
    console.log(svgContent[i].var);
}
```

it returns the same number repeatedly (its just overriding itself, since the way i have done it has linked every array element to the exact same variable svgData{}. 
How do I make an instance of a class (object)? And how do you link the constructor to the variable?

Comment: _"no link between this and the class"_ - what do you mean? Are you creating the object instances using `svgContent[i] = new SvgData()`?

Comment: no, but if I did, what is saying that the constructor SvgData() is even using the class? surely I could make a function called Create() and it would still work? In C# you write the constructor inside the class.

Comment: I think you need to read up on the differences between classical classes and javascript OOP. javascript does things a lot differently. A great resource is Programming Javascript Applications by Eric Elliot

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have classes as you know them.

Comment: Your "class" `var svgData` has no meaning. The function `SvgData` is basically your class definition. You could use a prototype though.

Comment: Could you post your class definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider the fact the JavaScript is a standalone language and implement things in its own way. From your question, I understand you want an array (which is still an object in JS, just with some special properties) of objects and you want those object to be made from a template (let's say a "class").

You've mentioned that there are no constructors, since there are no classes. But the way you've used `function SvgData` is exactly how you can design "classes". That's called a constructor function and it's special because it has no other statements than assignments to `this` object and thus it implicitly returns the `this` object (a constructor function is any function which returns the `this` object).

The syntax: `new SvgData` is basically syntax sugar for: create a new empty object (from "new") and assign to it the `this` object that is returned from whatever function comes next.

```js
function SvgData (val) {
    this.var = val;
}

var myLength = 10;
var myArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myLength; i ++) {
    myArr.push(new SvgData(i));
}

console.log(myArr);
```

This should do what you want it to do. You can test it [here](http://rextester.com/l/nodejs_online_compiler).

Answer (score 2):

You could easily change your code to get what you want (as far as I understand):

```
function SvgData(value) {
    this.var = value;
    // ...
}

// use this instead of your svgData variable:
SvgData.prototype = {
    // ...
}

var svgContent = [];

svgContent.push(new SvgData("value"));
```

[Read more on JavaScript prototypes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)